# loading jquery dependent library in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, datepicker

I used bootstrap-datepicker in the past which has an option to have a month calendar stay static (inline) as shown [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline).

I am now using React (and am pretty new at it), and need a date-picker again. I decided to use [react-bootstrap-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-date-picker) however react-bootstrap-datepicker does not have an inline option.

I don't want to heavily hack into the css for react-bootstrap-datepicker, what is the best way to load a jQuery dependent library such as bootstrap-datepicker on react? Would this be bad practice?

Here is the JS(jQuery)/HTML code for loading the bootstrap-datepicker module.

```
<div id="datepicker" data-date="12/03/2012"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
```

---

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();

$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {

    $('#my_hidden_input').val(
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
    );

});
```

UPDATE:

So while this did workout in terms of rendering the bootstrap calendar, I am not able to get the event to fire when #my_hidden_input's value has been updated. I added an onChange event to detect the value change for the div in the render() function.

```
<div id="datepicker"></div> 

    <div id="#my_hidden_input" onChange={this.handleDate}>

</div>
```

where the handleDate() function simply fires off a console.log(1);

Comment: Check out  `react-bootstrap-daterangepicker` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker) instead, I think that is what you were looking for. Creates a React component wrapper for bootstrap daterangepicker and gives you access to all of the same options as the original.

Comment: And here is an issue I opened with an example of how I add custom  classes and styles to the date picker. https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/141

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "React" way of initializing a jQuery plugin would be to do it in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

```
componentDidMount(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();

    $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {

        $('#my_hidden_input').val(
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
        );

    });
}
```

**Update:** Adding what @klaasman said concerning destroying or unmounting plugins. Use the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    $('#datepicker').destroy();
}
```

**Update 2:** The `onChange` event isn't firing because you you didn't set the event to call the `handleDate` function. Here, you set the change event to an anonymous function:

```
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {

    $('#my_hidden_input').val(
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
    );

});
```

Instead,  you need to supply your `handleDate` function like so:

```
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', this.handleDate);
```

Comment: I have also noticed that at times I need code to go in the lifecycle method componentWillUpdate() if you need a more dynamic behavior from the code.

Comment: Unless I completely missed it, after looking at the docs react-bootstrap-daterangepicker does not have an inline option unfortunately.

I opted for the jquery module solution, using componentDidMount().

Comment: It's also important not to forget to destroy such plugins on unmount, a library should support this. In this case, the bootstrap-datepicker supports a `.destroy()`-method, which will result in something like `$('#datepicker').data("DateTimePicker").destroy()`.